# Generic Base class inheriting from Generic Interface

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

For some reason I am battling to implement a property from a generic interface by using a generic base class as follows:

```
public interface IParent<TChild> where TChild : IChild
{
    TChild Child { get; }
}

public interface IChild { }
```

Then I have a base class:

```
public class ParentBase<TChild> : IParent<TChild> where TChild : IChild
{
    private TChild _child;
    public ParentBase(TChild child)
    {
        this._child = child;
    }
    #region IParent<TChild> Members

    public TChild Child
    {
        get { return _child; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now I have a new Parent Derivative and Child object as follows:

```
public class MyChild : IChild { }

public class MyParent : ParentBase<MyChild>, IParent<IChild> 
{
    public MyParent(MyChild child)
        : base(child)
    {
    }
}
```

I want to instantiate it and get the abstract (interface type) to pass to consumers as follows:

```
IParent<IChild> parent = new MyParent(new MyChild());
```

But for some reason I cannot implement the TChild correctly, even though I have defined the property `public TChild Child` on the ParentBase, the compiler says it is not implemented, even if i try implement explicitly.
As you can see the constraints are all the way through to the base class.

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Comment: I am using C# 4 (.NET 4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are deriving MyParent from `ParentBase<MyChild>` and `IParent<IChild>`.  There is no implementation for

```
IParent<IChild> { IChild Child{get; } }
```

Adding an explicit implementation will allow your original code to compile

```
public class MyParent : ParentBase<MyChild>, IParent<IChild>
{
    public MyParent(MyChild child)
        : base(child)
    {
    }

    #region Implementation of IParent<IChild>

    IChild IParent<IChild>.Child
    { 
        get { return base.Child; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

If you also make IParent covariant like this:

```
public interface IParent<out TChild> where TChild : IChild
{
    TChild Child { get; }
}
```

then you can now do this

```
IParent<IChild> parent = new MyParent(new MyChild());
```

or

```
ParentBase<MyChild> parent2 = new MyParent(new MyChild());
```

and

```
IParent<IChild> parent3 = parent2;
```

And as pointed out in the answer by @svick, with covariance you can then simplify by not deriving from `IParent<IChild>` and removing the explicit interface implementation.

Comment: The consumers need to use IParent<IChild> and not the concrete types so i need an instance of this. And when they access the child property it needs to just be IChild

Comment: The you need an explicit implementation nof IParent<IChild>.Child

Comment: But if you make `IParent` covariant and don't specify `IParent<IChild>` explicitly as a base for `MyParent`, then you won't have to implement `IParent<IChild>.Child`, the implementation in `ParentBase` will suffice. See my answer.

Comment: Very good point. I added the explicit implementation and then the 'out' keyword. +1

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly where generic variance is useful. If you marked your `IParent` interafce as covariant:

```
public interface IParent<out TChild> where TChild : IChild
```

and removed the explicit derivation of `IParent<IChild>` from `MyParent`:

```
public class MyParent : ParentBase<MyChild>
```

then `MyParent` can be treated as if it implemented `IParent<IChild>`. So for example, the following code would work:

```
MyParent parent = new MyParent(new MyChild());
IParent<IChild> iParent = parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the consumers need to use get an IChild and not a TChild, can you not get rid of the generic interface?

```
public interface IParent
{
    public IChild Child { get; }
}
```

and then your inheritance works just fine

```
public class ParentBase<TChild> : IParent where TChild : IChild
{
    public IChild Child { get { return myChild; } }
}
```

and

```
public class MyParent : ParentBase<MyChild> // already implements IParent by the base doing so.
{
}
```